# A hash-like object that acts like a case statement

Tags: ruby, hash, switch-statement

What is the best way to construct a hash-like class `Case`, which is initialized by a hash:

```
cs = Case.new(:a => 1, /b/ => 2, /c/ => 2, /d/ => 3)
```

and has a method `Case#[]` that looks up for the first matching key by `===` (like a case statement) instead of by `==` (like the conventional hash) and returns the value:

```
cs["xxb"] => 2
```

Comment: I can do it myself, but am looking for elegant solutions.

Comment: Is this too easy, or too difficult?

Comment: Or am I being ignored?

Comment: No you are not ignored.. You are very much respected here. :-) Trust me.

Comment: I am not so good at Ruby. But the way, you implemented the method `#[]`, is satisfactory...at-least for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility.

```
class Case
  def initialize(h)
    @h = h
  end
  def [](key,order=:PRE)
    case order
    when :PRE 
      h[@h.keys.find { |k| key === k }]
    when :POST
      h[@h.keys.find { |k| k === key }]
    else
      # raise exception
    end
  end
end

cs = Case.new(:a => 1, /b/ => 2, /c/ => 2, [1,2] => "cat", /d/ => 3)

cs["xxb"]        #=> nil
cs["xxb",:POST]  #=> 2
cs[Regexp]       #=> 2
cs[Regexp,:POST] #=> nil
cs[Array]        #=> "cat"
cs[Symbol]       #=> 1
```

This assumes `h` does not have a key `nil`.

---

With the understanding that the key in the hash is to come on the left side of `===`, the code would be:

```
class Case
  def initialize(h) @h = h end
  def [](key) h[@h.keys.find{|k| k === key}] end
end
```

Comment: It is ironical that you are using a case statement in an implementation to get away with case statement. Sorry if my question was not clear, but I only need the `:POST` case. And I wouldn't do `[1, 2] => "cat"`; I would do `1 => "cat", 2 => "cat"`.

Comment: What is the significance of `:POST` and `:PRE` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Unlike `==`, `===` is not symmetric, and you have to be aware which is the left side and which is the right. But I only need the `:POST` case.

Comment: @sawa, do you approve of my edit of your edit? Hmmm, I assume the hash won't have a key `k = nil`. (I removed my earlier comment to edit out a dumb observation.)